# MediaRecorder: start called in an invalid state: 4 in video recording

Tags: android

I am making a custom video recorder to record the video.Here is  my code

```
    boolean usecamera = true;
    boolean previewRunning = false;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    Button btnStart, btnStop;
    File root;
    File file;
    Boolean isSDPresent;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat;
    String timeStamp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_surface);
        initComs();
        actionListener();
    }

    private void initComs() {
        simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
        timeStamp = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
        camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

    }

    public static float megabytesAvailable(File f) {
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(f.getPath());
        long bytesAvailable = (long) stat.getBlockSize()
                * (long) stat.getAvailableBlocks();
        return bytesAvailable / (1024.f * 1024.f);
    }



    private void actionListener() {
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (recording) {
                    recorder.stop();
                    if (usecamera) {
                        try {
                            camera.reconnect();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    // recorder.release();
                    recording = false;
                    // Let's prepareRecorder so we can record again
                    prepareRecorder();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void prepareRecorder() {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        if (usecamera) {
            camera.unlock();
            recorder.setCamera(camera);
        }
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);

        recorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);



        if (camcorderProfile.fileFormat == MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4) {
            recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/XYZApp/" + "XYZAppVideo" + ""
                    + new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss").format(new Date())
                    + ".mp4");
        } else if (camcorderProfile.fileFormat == MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4) {
            recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/XYZApp/" + "XYZAppVideo" + ""
                    + new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss").format(new Date())
                    + ".mp4");
        } else {
            recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/XYZApp/" + "XYZAppVideo" + ""
                    + new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss").format(new Date())
                    + ".mp4");
        }

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        System.out.println("onsurfacecreated");

        if (usecamera) {
            camera = Camera.open();

            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                camera.startPreview();
                previewRunning = true;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                               int height) {
        System.out.println("onsurface changed");

        if (!recording && usecamera) {
            if (previewRunning) {
                camera.stopPreview();
            }

            try {
                Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

                p.setPreviewSize(camcorderProfile.videoFrameWidth,
                        camcorderProfile.videoFrameHeight);
                p.setPreviewFrameRate(camcorderProfile.videoFrameRate);

                camera.setParameters(p);

                camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                camera.startPreview();
                previewRunning = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

          prepareRecorder();
            if (!recording) {
                recording = true;
                recorder.start();
            }
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (recording) {
            recorder.stop();
            recording = false;
        }
        recorder.release();
        if (usecamera) {
            previewRunning = false;
            // camera.lock();
            camera.release();
        }
        finish();
    }
}
```

But when i am running this code it showing the error **MediaRecorder: start called in an invalid state: 4**.I didn't know what s the problem.I try everything from my side but nothing works.I am new in android please help me.

Comment: please add error log

Answer (score 0):

Please try that:

```
MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

mMediaRecorder.reset();
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(directory_path + path);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(width, height);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);                      

mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(bitrate);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(framerate);
int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation + 90);
mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
mMediaRecorder.prepare();
```